# reusing buffer pointers _before_ free

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I'm still kinda new to C, and especially dynamic memory allocation: Is it safe to reuse a buffer pointer in between its definition and possible `free` *without* re-initializing it?

I say possible free because the pointer could point to a statically allocated buffer:

```c
char buf[1024];
char *bufp = buf;
```

So if I have a buffer pointer called `tmp`, do I need to reinitialize it in order to *guarantee* that any previous assignments will be overwritten?

Are these safe:

- #### Pointer's memory filled by function

  ```c
  char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
  FILE *fp = fopen("/foo");

  // initial assignment
  fgets(tmp, sizeof tmp, fp);
  fclose(fp);

  fp = fopen("/bar");
  // does this replace the previous assignment?
  fgets(tmp, sizeof tmp, fp);

  fclose(fp);
  free(tmp);
  ```
- #### Pointer's memory filled inline

  ```c
  char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
  tmp = "foo";
  /* `tmp' gets used, but not free'd or assigned */

  tmp = "bar";
  /* ... */

  free(tmp);
  ```

Or should I assign `tmp` to `'\0'` (i.e. `tmp = '\0';`) or do something like `memset(tmp, '\0', sizeof tmp)` between each assignment

Comment: by `sizeof tmp` presumably you meant `1024`.  `tmp` is a pointer. `sizeof X` gives you the size of `X`, not the size of whatever `X` might be pointing to

Comment: @MattMcNabb how would I get the size of the memory allocated to `tmp`?  Would `sizeof &tmp` work?

Comment: use a variable or a constant to store the value, e.g. `const int buff_size = 1024;  tmp = malloc(buff_size); fgets(tmp, buff_size, fp);`

Comment: @MattMcNabb shouldn't `buff_size` be a `size_t`, or is the convention to use an `int` instead?

Comment: Yes it should be `size_t`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first code sample is OK (apart from the `sizeof` issue) . You allocate some memory, then write stuff into it, then overwrite it with other stuff.

In the second code example, it doesn't do what you think it does. The line:

```
tmp = "foo";
```

makes `tmp` point to the part of memory where `"foo"` is already stored. It doesn't copy `foo` into where `tmp` is currently pointing. This causes a memory leak because now there are no pointers to the area that you `malloc`'d.

The code should be:

```
char *tmp = malloc(1024);    // sizeof(char) always 1
strcpy(tmp, "foo");
strcpy(tmp, "bar");
free(tmp);
```

Comment: so the reason `tmp = "foo";` doesn't act like `char *tmp = "foo"` because of the `malloc`, right?

Comment: @AlexejMagura: It acts exactly the same. The issue is just that the previous value of the pointer is lost (and the pointer was the only one pointing to that chunk of memory), causing a leak.